# Div between 'display: flex' and 'flex-grow: 1' breaks layout

Tags: css, flexbox, polymer-1.0

I have a html

```
        <style>
            .container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                width: 400px;
                height: 400px;
                margin: 0 auto;
                border: solid 1px black;
            }
            .sub-container {
                display: flex;
                flex-direction: column;
                flex-grow: 1;
                //height: 100%;
                margin: 5px; 
                border: solid 1px yellow; 
            }
            .red-block {
                margin: 5px; 
                border: solid 1px red;
            }
            .green-block {
                flex-grow: 1;
                margin: 5px; 
                border: solid 1px green;
                overflow-y: auto;
            }
            .blue-block {
                margin: 5px; 
                border: solid 1px blue;
            }
        </style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="red-block">HEADER</div>

    <div class="sub-container" > <!-- Polymer module -->
        <!-- shady dom -->
        <div class="green-block">
            <div style="height: 500px;">CENTER</div>
        </div>
        <div class="blue-block">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ueODu6Xqz7K0uifRiQBm?p=preview)

As you can see the content is outside of main block (black border). 
If I remove  (yellow border) then the result will be ok.
But I use Polymer.js and when I add my dom-module to the page I get excess div (sub-container) which breaks my layout.

How to make sub-container do not effect on layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use flex-basis: 0; for the div to force fit inside the container. 
add flex-basis:0; to .green-block class to get the desired effect

http://plnkr.co/edit/Xj6fe8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <style>
    .container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 400px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: solid 1px black;
    }

    .sub-container {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      flex-grow: 1;
      //height: 100%;
      margin: 5px;
      border: solid 1px yellow;
    }

    .red-block {
      margin: 5px;
      border: solid 1px red;
    }

    .green-block {
      flex-basis: 0;
      flex-grow: 1;
      margin: 5px;
      border: solid 1px green;
      overflow-y: auto;
    }

    .blue-block {
      margin: 5px;
      border: solid 1px blue;
    }

    .traitor {
      height: 500px;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="red-block">HEADER</div>

    <div class="sub-container">
      <!-- Polymer module -->
      <!-- shady dom -->
      <div class="green-block">
        <div class="traitor">CENTER</div>
      </div>
      <div class="blue-block">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment if this is not what you are asking about!

Answer (score 0):

Now I get it work. 
One needs to add to sub-container:

```
height: 0px;
flex-grow: 1;
```

Due to height: 0px; element will not depend on a big children elements.
http://plnkr.co/edit/bbqsTJiguBXFlzySpLRu?p=preview